# N value in a GWAS?

Tags: genetics, gwas

Just like the title says. I am reading about a GWAS but I don't know much about them. I understood most of it but I couldn't figure out what the "n" value was.

Comment: Are you talking about `n` (as written in the title) or `N` (as written in the title)? The meaning of a variable like this might well vary depending on your source. Can you please indicate your source?

Comment: Same question as @Remi.b. The most common use of $n$ is to denote the total number of subjects used in the study. $N$ is also often used to denote the number of alleles.